# Nativ Popup with Options in GWT

Tags: gwt, popup, native

I'm currently building the mobile interfaces for my GWT app and I noticed that using `Window.alert("message")` invoked the phones native pop up panel. I was wondering if is possible to do this but have different buttons (rather than just "okay") in the pop up? This would be a lot simpler than writing a separate pop up panel.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the native popup behavior. you have to use [PopUpPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/PopupPanel.html) and [DialogBox](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DialogBox.html) for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can have `OK` and `Cancel` buttons if you use `Window.confirm()` (or `Window.prompt()`). No other options for native pop-up.